# Changing multiple classes into multiple li's with click event

Tags: jquery, css

i tried to do some search but i didn't figured out how to do what do i need.

```
<ul>
  <li class="_0mb"></li>
  <li class="_3mb"></li>
  <li class="_7mb"></li>
  <li class="_14mb"></li>
  <li class="_20mb"></li>
  <li class="oltre_20mb"></li>
</ul>
```

what i need to do is to give to the user the ability to switch between different filters clicking on one of those `li` tags, this would fire different backgrounds based upon where the user makes the click. Every `li` tag has a white background as default and an image when clicked.

I know how to manipulate classes with `.addClass` and `.removeClass`, but i need to change classes both to the `li` the user clicked on and to all of the preceeding `li` tags to "activate" the button changing the background image (eg. if the user clicks on `_7mb` i need to change the background also to `_3mb` and `0_mb`), and i have no idea how to do it.

Similarly i need to change all of the subsequent `li` tags "deactivating" them, removing the background image if any, when the user - for example - makes a first click to `_20mb` and then a click back to `_7mb`.

Comment: The same background image or different ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select all previous siblings with jquery and add them css class:

```
$("li").on('click', function(){
  $('li').removeClass('red');
  $(this).addClass('red');
  $(this).prevAll().addClass('red');
})
```

Comment: `$(this).addClass('red').prevAll().addClass('red');`

Comment: That's exactly what i've been looking for, many thanks! only one more question: if i try to click the last `li`, everything works as expected, and also clicking backward to the second `li`, but when i try to click back to the first `li` i see that the red color won't go away, how your code should be modified to get that behaviour?

Comment: I am not sure that I know what you mean. Do you need to deselect first list item too, or it stops working when you click last -> second -> first?

Comment: The first you said, i need to be able to deselect also the first item too, when clicking on it when it's active. Tried with this code without success: `if($(this).hasClass('active')) { $(this).removeClass('active');}`

Comment: I guess it was a misunderstanding then, but it is no problem to do that.
**Example 1** deselect only works when you click on first item, and no other items are selected: http://jsfiddle.net/9m5wP/1/
**Example 2** deselect works on every selected item: http://jsfiddle.net/9m5wP/2/

Comment: Thank you uross, second example it's exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: No problem. Look at this example, code here is much cleaner: http://jsfiddle.net/9m5wP/4/

Answer (score 0):

On the DOM-element you can use `.previousSiblings` to get the li elements that come before the li element that the user clicked on.

If you want to use a jQuery object you can call `.prev()` on the element that was clicked to get the previous sibling. You will have to call `.prev()`again on that sibling and so on in order to get all the previous Siblings. Or you can use the `.prevAll()` to get all previous siblings.

your code could look something like this:

```
$(li).click(function(){
  $(this).addClass('clicked');
  $(this).siblings().removeClass('clicked');
  $(this).prevAll().changeButton();
});
```

Comment: Or use jQuery's `.prevAll()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('activated');
  $(this).prevAll().addClass('activated');
  $(this).nextAll().removeClass('activated');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li').click(function () {
    $(this).siblings().addBack(this).removeClass('activate notActive clicked');
    $(this).addClass('clicked').prevAll().addClass('activate').end().nextAll().addClass('notActive');
});
```

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/uHmda/